# Expected identifier but found "*" [css-syntax-error] while updating angular 10 to 14

Tags: css, angular, typescript, error-handling, angular14

When I updated my angular version from 10 to 14, at the time of making build I have seen warning in command prompt. The error as below:-

Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Expected identifier but found "*" [css-syntax-error]

```
styles.css:1617:2:
  1617 │   *cursor: hand;
       ╵   ^
```

SS:-

[image]

Remove this CSS syntax error from commant prompt while making the build.

Comment: Why do you have those stars in your selectors ?

Comment: It will added automatically at the time of updation. Evenly I didn't find these propery anywhere in css file.

Comment: Well that is strange... but what is your question?

Comment: I have updated my angular version from 10 to 14. Now when I making the build this warning pops up in comand prompt. But this CSS property I can't found anywhere in css file. Now I want to remove this property from command prompt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After Angular update I found those warnings are from: "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"

reinstalling the package:

npm i datatables.net-dt

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

change your css file extensions from css->scss. This works for me while deploying on vercel.